# Can you skip a line within a ul list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an unordered list of multiple items. I want to put in a line break between sections in the list without breaking the `ul` group? Is this possible?

Let's say it looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
  <li>item 9</li>
  <li>item 10</li>
</ul>
```

So, let's say that visually I want the list to display with a line-break between items 3 and 4 or between items 7 and 8. Is there a way to insert an LI item that's blank that acts as a line-break without it displaying a bullet point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list-style:none on a `<li>` with a non breaking space.

```
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
<li>item 5</li>
<li style="list-style:none;">&nbsp;</li>
<li>item 7</li>
<li>item 8</li>
<li>item 9</li>
<li>item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That did precisely what I needed. I thought I had the syntax right when I tried this before, but apparently I didn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) or [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type), setting `margin-top` to which `n` child you want

#### Snippet for both your cases » <sub>item 3/4 and 7/8</sub>

```css
li:nth-child(4n+4) {
  margin-top:10px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
  <li>item 9</li>
  <li>item 10</li>
</ul>
```

#### Snippet for » <sub>item 3/4</sub>

```css
li:nth-child(4) {
  margin-top:10px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
  <li>item 9</li>
  <li>item 10</li>
</ul>
```

#### Snippet for » <sub>item 7/8</sub>

```css
li:nth-child(8) {
  margin-top:10px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
  <li>item 9</li>
  <li>item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The nth-child is a way to do it ( also using * too but that may be too much ). Then just add padding or margin to separte the next section to how much you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/vqjq9gcz/

```
ul li:nth-child(4n + 4){
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `li:nth-child(x)` with a margin-bottom setting, where x is the line/s after which you want to have the distance, for example:

```
li:nth-child(3), li:nth-child(7) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrmbGy

Comment: This might work if I didn't have to set different positions for the line break for different lists throughout the site.

Comment: well, assign different classes to the different `ul` tags and use combined selectors accordingly, like  `.my_list_1 li:nth-child(3), .my_list_1 li:nth-child(7) { ... }`, `.my_list_2 li:nth-child(5), .my_list_2 li:nth-child(11) { ... }` etc.

Comment: and (since you seem to prefer that) you could as well insert these margins as inline styles in the `li` tags, like `<li style="margin-bottom: 20px">` wherever you need it.

Answer (score -1):

Without CSS, this may work. I'm not sure about validation or cross browser support, however.

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li><br>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is invalid html, `br` can't be direct child of `ul`

Comment: If you put the `<br>` inside the `<li>` it would be valid.

Comment: But that would display an extra bullet point. Better to go with one of the valid solutions or stick with this invalid approach.

Comment: I tried something like this (<br /><br /> after the line) and it only created a bullet point with no entry.

Comment: Do you see a bullet point with no entry when you click the Run Snippet button?